# Почему в methods Vue функция работает без указания слова function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Недавно начал изучать Vue и после перехода с python случайно написал такой код:

```
methods: {
    foo() {},
}
```

Код работает точно так же как, если бы написать корректно:

```
methods: {
    foo: function() {},
}
```

Собственно. Почему работает первый вариант? Просмотрел документацию и JS, и Vue. Не могу найти подобный синтаксис.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript 2015:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

> Сокращенная запись метода объекта.

Answer (score 0):

foo: function() {} это анонимная функция

foo() {} это метод или функция в классе

Так же можно написать 
foo: () => {}

При вызове данных методов не возникнет никаких проблем